# pop to rootviewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I used multiple storyboard to my app as individual,
like 
Login--->Otp--->homepage(Tabbarcontroller)---->profileview--->settings
every viewcontroller had separate storyboard.navigatoin controller start from loginview. 
in setting page had singout button. when I click singout button I have to show loginview controller 
but when I click on singout button it will pop to profile view, I tried popToRootview controller.
I used many way but nothing is workout, when I click settings button I have to show login view controller how can I achieve.

```
  @objc func signoutClicked(_ sender :UIButton)
{

      self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
        self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

       })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would not work because you are using `UITabBarController`. What you need to do is put Login and OTP ViewControllers in a navigational stack once it's successfully complete use `present(, animated:)` method to go to your TabBarController. When the user logs out `dismiss(animated:)` method to go back to login navigational stack.

In LoginViewController -> OTPController:

```
func handleLoginSuccess() {
    // ...
    present(myTabBarController, animated: true)
}
```

In ProfileViewController -> SettingsController

```
func handleLogout() {
    // ...
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. How to logout**

You have to change **root view controller** as a Login View Controller

**Try the code below**

```
@objc func signoutClicked(_ sender :UIButton) {
    AppDelegate.shared.window?.openLogin()
}

extension AppDelegate {

    static var shared: AppDelegate {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }
}

extension UIWindow {

    func openLogin() {
        let loginVC = YourLoginViewController()
        self.changeRootViewController(to: loginVC)
    }

    func openHomePage() {
        let loginVC = YourHomePageViewController()
        self.changeRootViewController(to: loginVC)
    }

    func changeRootViewController(to desiredViewController: UIViewController) {
        if rootViewController != nil,
            let snapshot = self.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true) {

            desiredViewController.view.addSubview(snapshot)

            for view in subviews {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            rootViewController = desiredViewController

            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: 0.3,
                delay: 0,
                options: .curveEaseOut,
                animations: {
                    snapshot.layer.opacity = 0
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        } else {
            rootViewController = desiredViewController
        }
    }
}
```

**2. How to login into HomePage**

Just call

```
AppDelegate.shared.window?.openHomePage()
```